# ReactJs: Prevent Rerender of wrapped component

Tags: reactjs, render

I'm trying to prevent a re-render when using custom hook for hours now -.-, need some help ;O|

*(Dont know if I should call this custom hook or functional hoc though)*

I have a MessageList component that display a SimpleMessage wrapped in WithAvatarHeader.
Here is my profiler result:
[image: profile result]

Every time I add a message to the list, all messages are rendered again.

This isn't happening when I only use SimpleMessage in MessageList

Is there a way to memo(WithAvatarHeader) ?

MessageList :

```
import React from "react";
import SimpleMessage from "./SimpleMessage";
import WithAvatarHeader from "./WithAvatarHeader";


const MessageList = props => {
  const Message = WithAvatarHeader(SimpleMessage);
  return (
    <div className="message-list">
      {props.messages.map(message => {
        return <Message message={message} key={message._id}/>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

SimpleMessage:

```
import React, { memo } from "react";

const SimpleMessage = props => {
  return (
    <div className="simple-message">
      {props.message}
    </div>
  );
};

export default memo(SimpleMessage);
```

WithAvatarHeader:

```
import React from "react";

const WithAvatarHeader = WrappedComponent => props => {
  return <WrappedComponent {...props} />;
};

export default WithAvatarHeader;
```

Thanks for the help :-)

Comment: You should use `key` prop in `Message` `<Message message={message} key={message} />`

Comment: You can do ```const WithAvatarHeader = WrappedComponent => memo(props => {
  return <WrappedComponent {...props} />;
))``` but your problem is not having unique keys in your map

Comment: Yeah sorry, edited it, I cleaned the code a bit too much and removed key attribute, will try your solution.

Comment: Still trigger a re-render on every messages, except i'v got an anonymouse(memo) in profiler now :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not declare component inside another component.

Once you move declaration outside:

```
const Message = WithAvatarHeader(SimpleMessage);
const MessageList = props => {
  return (
    <div className="message-list">
      {props.messages.map(message => {
        return <Message message={message} key={message._id}/>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

you will be fine.

Reason is [reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) process that decides what's to drop, what to create and what to update.

Besides your JSX says it still same element `<Message>` React checks component's constructor(it does not work with text representation from JSX). And it will referentially different(since you re-declare this constructor on next render). So React drops every `<Message>` and create them from scratch. Keeping declaration outside your `MessageList` means constructor is referentially the same so React will not re-create `<Message>` till `key` is the same.